# problem with bootstrap form select and its validation

Tags: bootstrap-4

I need advice with a boostrap. Attached is a picture select, I can't figure it out as in the boostrap, move the cross from the validation further from the edge so that it doesn't look so bad.
How can you cross the cross more from the region but to keep the form responsive?
Thank you for the advice.

```
<`
 <form   method="post" class="was-validated" novalidate>
 <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="DruhVozidla" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><?php echo "Druh Vozidla"; ?></label>
                <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
                    <select  name="DruhVozidla" style = "background-position-x: 175px;"class="form-control form-select is-invalid  <?php echo (!empty($RZ_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" required aria-label="select example" value="<?php echo $DruhVoz; ?>"  required min="0">
                    <option selected disabled value="">Vyberte hodnotu</option>
                    <option value="A">Ano</option>
                    <option value="N">Ne</option>
                    </select>
                    <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-container=".row" data-content="Vyberte druh vozidla" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover"></i></span></div>
                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $DruhVozidla_err; ?></div>
                 </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
</form>
'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will send the attachment what the select with validation looks like. I apologize for the English via google translator. Thank you[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdCKB.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form  method="post" class="was-validated" novalidate>
<div class="form-group row">
              <label for="TankKartaHotovost" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right"><?php echo "Tankovací karta / hotovost na cestu"; ?></label>
              <div class="col-md-7">
              <div class="input-group input-group-sm ">
                  <select  name="DruhVozidla"  required aria-label="select example"  class="form-control form-select is-invalid  <?php echo (!empty($RZ_err)) ? 'is-invalid' : ''; ?>" value="<?php echo $DruhVoz; ?>"  required min="0">
                  <option selected disabled value="">Vyberte hodnotu</option>
                  <option value="A">Ano</option>
                  <option value="N">Ne</option>
                  </select>
                  <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-question-circle" data-toggle="popover" data-container=".row" data-content="Vyberte druh vozidla" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover"></i></span></div>
                  <div class="invalid-feedback order-1" ><?php echo $DruhVozidla_err; ?></div>
               </div>
               </div>
            </div>

</form>
```